# Does BFS or DFS perform better to solve the Towers of Hanoi problem?

Tags: search-algorithms

> Use the DFS and BFS algorithms to solve the Towers of Hanoi problem. Which performs better and why?

[Towers of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi)

[Towers of Hanoi visualization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YstLjLCGmgg)

When I think of the Towers of Hanoi problem, I think of moving the three disks in a LIFO order. The last disk you place on a rod must be the first one to move off the rod. Since the depth-first search algorithm is an instance of the graph-search algorithm that uses a LIFO queue, would I be correct to say depth-first search outperforms breadth-first search to solve the Towers of Hanoi problem?

Comment: I don't really understand your reasoning. It seems a bit like saying that cars are powered by lots of small explosions and machine guns are powered by lots of small explosions, so it's better to carry machine guns in a car than on a horse.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I don't know the answer to the question. The textbook I'm reading tells me that DFS is associated with problems solved by using a LIFO queue. From my understanding of Towers of Hanoi, it seems to me that it would be better solved by DFS.

Comment: Have you tried implementing both algorithms for some simple cases such as 3 disks? Use an counter to record the number of moves that have been tried.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I just tried it and BFS was way better than DFS.

Comment: @Robby Nice. Can you describe briefly your BFS and DFS algorithms _in the question_? Add a link in some online IDE to your code _in the questino_. Think about your findings and arguments. I encourage you to write them as an answer. If not bad, I will upvote.